# Can't shutdown laptop

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Whenever I press "shut down" from the menu bar nothing happens. It's like I never pressed it. Everytime I want to turn off my laptop I have to manually press and hold the power button which is a hassle. How do I fix this? The system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Try <code>sudo shutdown -h now</code> from the terminal.

Comment: @Jay you can use backticks in comments for `code formatting`